# How to plot mean_test score and mean_train score of GridSearchCV

Tags: svm, grid-search

How to plot `mean_train_score` and `mean_test_score` values in `GridSearchCV` for `C` and `gamma` values of SVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could visualize them as a [heatmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map).

For example you could use the `C` values as the rows, the `gamma` values as the columns and the color intensity of each element in the heatmap array would correspond to the `mean_test_score`.

To implement this you first need to create a `pandas.DataFrame` like this:

$$
\begin{array}{c | c c c}
  & C   & gamma & mean\_test\_score \\ \hline 
1 & 0.1 & 0.001 & 0.798 \\
2 & 1   & 0.001 & 0.813 \\
3 & 1   & 0.01  & 0.801 \\
4 & 10  & 0.001 & 0.787 \\
\end{array}
$$

To do this you need to store each run you make in a different line, which will contain all necessary hyper-parameters and the result. Then you will need to make a pivot table which will use `C` as the rows, `gamma` as the columns and `mean_test_score` as the values.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values=df['mean_test_score'])
```

This pivot will be the array that will form your heatmap. Now you should select your aesthetic parameters (e.g. colormap) and proceed to make the heatmap.

```
sns.heatmap(pivot) # plus any other aesthetic parameters you wish
```

Comment: Yes.. Please update on how to implement that..

Comment: @HarikaM I added a way to implement this in python